# Why are some apt-get-installed fonts being ignored by fc-list, xfontsel, etc?

Tags: debian, x11, fonts, fontconfig

Even after I run `dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig` (and getting the message `Regenerating fonts cache... done.`), font-related programs such as `fc-list`, `xfontsel`, `gnome-font-viewer`, etc. omit some fonts contained in packages (e.g. `xfonts-cyrillic`) that I have previously installed (with `apt-get`).

The files for the omitted fonts get installed under `/usr/share/fonts`, one of the directories specified in my system-wide `fonts.conf` file.  It's worth noting that, e.g. `fc-list` *does* list many *other* fonts under this directory.

Why are these fonts being ignored?

EDIT: FWIW, doing `xset fp rehash` did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one point:

- `xfonts-cyrillic` is a bitmap font and normally not shown with `fc-list`.
- bitmap fonts are shown with `xlsfonts`
- in turn, that uses the X server's fontpath, which you can see using `xset q`, e.g.,

```
   Font Path:
     /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,built-ins
```

Though the manual page says `cyrillic` is in the default configuration, it is not — until you restart X.  Then you would see something like this:

```
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,built-ins
```

If you do not see that, you can always add to the fontpath by adding an Xorg configuration file as noted in [Additional font path for Xorg, but no xorg.conf](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142648).

Once it is in your fontpath, you should be able to see this font using `xlsfonts '*cronyx*'`, e.g.,

```
-cronyx-courier-bold-o-normal--0-0-100-100-m-0-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-bold-o-normal--14-100-100-100-m-80-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-bold-o-normal--17-120-100-100-m-90-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-bold-o-normal--20-140-100-100-m-120-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-bold-r-normal--0-0-100-100-m-0-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-bold-r-normal--14-100-100-100-m-80-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-bold-r-normal--17-120-100-100-m-90-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-bold-r-normal--20-140-100-100-m-120-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-medium-o-normal--0-0-100-100-m-0-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-medium-o-normal--14-100-100-100-m-80-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-medium-o-normal--17-120-100-100-m-90-koi8-r
-cronyx-courier-medium-o-normal--20-140-100-100-m-120-koi8-r
```

as well as with `xfontsel`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused by your assertion on `fc-list` and bitmapped fonts.  When I run `fc-list`, the output I get includes several bitmapped fonts, including Terminus and Clean, among others...

Comment: I said "normally".  You can configure a bitmap font to be found by `fc-list`, but it does not by default use the same indices as the X server, so requires more work.  Only a small fraction of the bitmap-fonts on my system are shown with `fc-list`.  Sometime I may write a how-to (since there seems to be none...).

Comment: At list for `terminus`, when one runs `apt-get install xfonts-terminus`, `50-enable-terminus.conf` gets added to `/etc/fonts/conf.d`, and this file does have an `<acceptfont>` section culminating in `<patelt name="family"><string>terminus</string></patelt>`, as you say.  In order to replicate this recipe, though, I need a way to find the magic string to replace `???` with in `<patelt name="family"><string>???</string></patelt>`, for each omitted font.  My usual way of getting such font info is from `fc-list -v`, but obviously that won't work in this case...  More digging ahead.  Thanks again.